# Embed CSV data in SQL file for import

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite you can import data from a CSV file such as the following:

```
create table foo(a, b);
.mode csv
.import test.csv foo
```

These lines could be stored in a text file themselves, and run using `sqlite3 foo.db < foo.txt` to create database file foo.db.

So this approach requires two separate file - one to store the import commands, and the second CSV data file itself.

**It there any way to embed the CSV data directly into a script which also contains the import commands?**

Comment: Could you contrast what you are trying to do and the use of `.dump` after importing only the csv into an empty databse? The result would be a text (easily written into e.g. a import.sql file) which could be used by `.read`? I guess it is not what you want, but why exactly?

Comment: @Yunnosch the reason for using the CSV files is just file size - for cases of thousands or records, the "INSERT INTO xxx..." text adds up considerably. Using CSV format gets around that but at the cost of a little more complexity to maintain things. I think the IMPORT idea would produce a set of SQL commands which would work but doesn't meet that objective.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to minimize the file size is to use a compressed file:

```
gunzip -c foo.txt.gz | sqlite3 foo.db
```

Comment: This is a file used in development and will be maintained in source control so compressing it would be counterproductive. In other scenarios of course that would be the simplest approach. Thanks.